# Use SORT option directlly in component instad of PIPE in HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

I get data from ngrx-store with selector and set data to `observable`

```
allData$: Observable<IGetData>;

this.allData$ = this.store.select(
      fromStore.dataSelector.getAllData,
    );

this.allData$.subscribe((data) => this.allData = data.dataPages)

// data example
{
   "id":2340,
   "dataPages":[
      {
         "id":324,
         "position":0,
         "data":[
            {
               "id":0,
               "name":"data1",
               "text":"data1",
               "position":0,
               "dataControls":[
                  {
                     "id":0,
                     "name":"control3",
                     "position":0
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":1,
               "position":1,
               "dataControls":[
                  {
                     "id":351,
                     "position":0,
                     "inputControls":[
                        {
                           "id":453,
                           "position":0
                        },
                        {
                           "id":5345,
                           "position":1
                        },
                        {
                           "id":3453,
                           "position":2
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":31,
         "position":1,
         "data":[
            {
               "id":1231,
               "position":0,
               "dataControls":[
                  {
                     "id":31231,
                     "position":120
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":234,
               "position":1,
               "dataControls":[
                  {
                     "id":351,
                     "position":0,
                     "inputControls":[
                        {
                           "id":453,
                           "position":0
                        },
                        {
                           "id":5345,
                           "position":1
                        },
                        {
                           "id":3453,
                           "position":2
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I in this array I add/remove/edit items, so array is not immutable.

And in HTML I use this data with multiple `*ngFor` loops

```
<div *ngFor="let page of allData">
  <div *ngFor="let data1 of page">
    <div *ngFor="let data of data1">
      <div *ngFor="let dataControls of data">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to sort all data in every `*ngFor` loop by the `POSITION`, and I create custom PIPE to done this directly in HTML

```
    <div *ngFor="let page of allData | sortBy: 'position'">
      <div *ngFor="let data1 of page | sortBy: 'position'">
        <div *ngFor="let data of data1 | sortBy: 'position'">
          <div *ngFor="let dataControls of data | sortBy: 'position'">
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my PIPE

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sortBy',
})
export class SortByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any, field: string): any[] {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
      return;
    }
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[field] < b[field]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

And this is working **excellent**, 
but **this is an anti-pattern**. 
[angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe](http://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

And I try to move this to the component, but in my `*ngFor` loop my data are still UN-SORTED.

I try to `map` my OBSERVABLE

```
this.allData$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromStore.dataSelector.getNewData),
  map((data) => data.dataPages.sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position)),
);
```

And here, also, I stuck because I need to go DEEP to the array and `sortBy` every nested array by own `POSITION` key, but I don't know how to do this on clever way.

Thnx

Comment: Isn't your `ngFor` syntax invalid? You've closed off the `ngFor` portion after `let ... of ...`

Comment: @Edric I need to use nested "*ngFor". I don't understand your question?

Comment: For example, `*ngFor="let page of allData" | sortBy: "position"` should be `*ngFor="let page of allData | sortBy: 'position'"`.

Comment: You're right, I wrote this as an example so I accidentally skipped it

Comment: I always suggest sorting your object in your API first. If you must do a sort 4 loops deep (which has a complexity of O(n^8)) then you'll need to map through each later and return the sorted objects. I found this link and thought it would be helpful. It's a recursive example of sorting multi dimensional arrays. https://coderwall.com/p/5fu9xw/how-to-sort-multidimensional-array-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can create a sortByPosition pipe:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'sortByPosition' })
export class SortByPositionPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: ReadonlyArray<{position: number}>) {
    return [...input].sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position);
  }
}
```

It's a pure pipe, so make sure that the input is immutable. E.g:

```js
interface Data {
  id: number;
  dataPages: ReadonlyArray<{
    id: number;
    position: number;
    data: ReadonlyArray<...>;
  }>;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have already created pipe on this way, but I hope i can instead in html sort directly in the componenti. Btw,  what you mean when you say INPUT IS IMMUTABLE?

Comment: That means your arrays should be immutable: you can't do something like `data.dataPages.push(...)` as it modifies the array. The easiest way to make sure that your arrays are immutable is declaring them ReadonlyArray<X> instead of Array<X>

Comment: Thnx. I will try your pipe. And this PURE pipe is ok for performance and minification considerations? I put in my questin what kind of pipe I use just now, pls take a look is this ok? Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is ok for performance (as it is pure) and minification (no string as sort field). In your case, you still use the string 'position' in html template.

Comment: Yes, this is ok and thank you, but problem is with immutable array, because I use this array to add/remove/edit items in array :/

Comment: That's the reason why Angular team does not provide a sort / filter pipe: people would use them in mutable arrays ==> You need to make impure pipe ==> Bad for performance. Immutable array is a way to make sure that sort is not executed when it is not necessary. Another way to do is removing the sort pipe and making sure that your arrays are always sorted when you are modifying them (I do not like this because you will always forget one place to sort...)

Comment: Ok, do you have suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: You should learn how to work with immutable data, especially when you are working with ngrx. Otherwise, you should accept that your application does not have best performance. It may be enough in most cases, except if you have a big collection of data.

Comment: but that is exactly why I ask here for help for this case. Thnx

Comment: You need to make a copy of your array each time you modify it, and its parents, such as: data.dataPage = [...data.dataPages, newItem] to add a new item. Since you need to modify its parents as well, your object is too deep to make it easily editable. There is no absolute way to organize your state, your should decide it yourself. You can have some information in redux site: https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#how-do-i-organize-nested-or-duplicate-data-in-my-state